# Check if vector in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix

```
new<-matrix(9,4,4)
new[1,1]<-0

v1<-c(0,0)
```

new thus looks like this:

```
0 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9
```

I now want to check if this matrix contains the vector v1.
So I did

```
v1 %in% new
```

and obtain TRUE TRUE
although I would like to check the whole vector of two zeros in a row/ column and thus
would like to get a FALSE.

Comment: So if there are ever two 0 in a row horizontally/vertically you want to obtain `TRUE`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rollapply` from `zoo` to test if *matrix contains a vector*:

```
library(zoo)
any(apply(new, 2, rollapply, length(v1), identical, v1))
#[1] FALSE

new[2,1] <- 0
any(apply(new, 2, rollapply, length(v1), identical, v1))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

The vector has two values, so if you want to check whether it is contained in the matrix you will have to paste the two values together to obtain `0,0`:

```
paste0(v1, collapse = ",") %in% new
[1] FALSE
```

or this, which compares the string `0,0` from the pasted-together vector to the pasted-together rows of the matrix:

```
paste0(v1, collapse = ",") %in% apply(new, 2, paste0, collapse = ",")
[1] FALSE
```

or this, which searches for `0,0` in the corresponding pairs of two digts separated by comma in the pasted-together rows of the matrix:

```
library(stringr)
paste0(v1, collapse = ",") %in% unlist(str_split(apply(new, 2, paste0, collapse = ","), "(?<=\\d,\\d),(?=\\d,\\d)"))
```

This latter solution seems the most likely as it searches for `0,0` `%in%` this vector, which is the output of `unlist(str_split(apply(new, 2, paste0, collapse = ","), "(?<=\\d,\\d),(?=\\d,\\d)"))`:

```
[1] "0,9" "9,9" "9,9" "9,9" "9,9" "9,9" "9,9" "9,9"
```

Comment: Thank you! That already helps a lot. How would I have to edit the code to look for matrices within a matrix? So that not only a horizontal vector (0,0) but to differentiate between a (1,2) and (2,1) matrix with entries (0,0)?

Comment: I guess that'll merit a new question. Please consider accepting or upvoting my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately my votes are not yet cast due to too low reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `isTRUE` and `all.equal`, while `intersect` the vector with the matrix i.e.

```
isTRUE(all.equal(v1, intersect(v1, new)))
#[1] FALSE

v2 <- c(0, 9)
all.equal(v2, intersect(v2, new))
#[1] TRUE
```