# Check if matrix in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix

```
new<-matrix(9,4,4)
new[1,1]<-0
new[2,1]<-0

m1<-matrix(0,2,1)
m2<-matrix(0,1,2)
```

the matrices thus looks like this:

```
m1:
0
0

m2:
0 0 

new:
0 9 9 9 
0 9 9 9
9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9
```

I now want to check if this matrix contains the matrices m1 or m2.
So I did

```
m1 %in% new 
m2 %in% new
```

and obtain TRUE TRUE for both
but would like to get TRUE for m1 and FALSE for m2

Comment: Isn't there an answer in your previous question [Check if vector in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62693039/10488504) ?

Answer (score 0):

As your example matrix `m1` and `m2` can be converted to vectors you can use my previous answer at [Check if vector in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62693039/10488504).

```
library(zoo)
any(apply(new, 2, rollapply, length(m1), identical, c(m1)))
#[1] TRUE

any(apply(new, 1, rollapply, length(m2), identical, c(m2)))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying to do it without other packages but that certainly helps

Answer (score 0):

A vectorised solution can be to use `which` with argument of `arr.ind = TRUE` and play with the rows of the matrix. i.e.

```
i_new <- which(new == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]
i_m1 <- which(m1 == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]
i_m2 <- which(m2 == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]


Reduce(`-`, i_new) == Reduce(`-`, i_m1)
#[1] TRUE
Reduce(`-`, i_new) == Reduce(`-`, i_m2)
#[1] FALSE
```

To see how and why this works you simply need to investigate the `i_*`, i.e.

```
 which(m1 == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1

which(m2 == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   1   2

which(new == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `rle` in a function that `*apply`es it on rows and columns.

```
vecCheck <- function(mat, v, n) {
  l <- unlist(lapply(1:2, function(x) apply(mat, x, rle)), recursive=F)
  any(unlist(sapply(l, function(x) x$lengths[x$values == v] == n)))
}

new <- matrix(9, 4, 4)
vecCheck(new, 0, 2)
# [1] FALSE

new[1:2, 1 ] <- 0
vecCheck(new, 0, 2)
# [1] TRUE
```